# Stored procedure returning the wrong value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that check holidays that are booked off in my database and it should not take into account holidays with a status of 'Declined' or 'Cancelled', yet o have only one record in my database which has a status of declined but this select statement returns 1?

```
        SELECT COUNT(*) JobRoleID
        FROM        Employees
        RIGHT JOIN  Holidays
        ON          Employees.ID = Holidays.EmployeeID
        WHERE       Holidays.Status <> 'Declined' AND Holidays.Status <> 'Cancelled'
        AND        (Holidays.Startdate <= '2014/04/28' AND Holidays.Enddate >= '2014/04/30')
        OR         (Holidays.Startdate >= '2014/04/28' AND Holidays.Enddate <= '2014/04/30') 
        OR         (Holidays.Startdate <= '2014/04/30' AND Holidays.Enddate >= '2014/04/30') 
        OR         (Holidays.Startdate <= '2014/04/28' AND Holidays.Enddate >= '2014/04/28') 
        OR         (Holidays.StartDate = '2014/04/28' AND Holidays.EndDate = '2014/04/30')
```

Comment: What is the status of the holiday for this row returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator precedence needs to be taken into consideration here.

```
Not -->  AND --> OR
```

Not takes precedence over AND , AND takes precedence over OR. With these nested ANDs and ORs it is always better to put them in paranthesis.

```
WHERE       Holidays.[Status] <> 'Declined' AND Holidays.[Status] <> 'Cancelled'
AND    
    (       (Holidays.Startdate <= '2014/04/28' AND Holidays.Enddate >= '2014/04/30')
        OR  (Holidays.Startdate >= '2014/04/28' AND Holidays.Enddate <= '2014/04/30') 
        OR  (Holidays.Startdate <= '2014/04/30' AND Holidays.Enddate >= '2014/04/30') 
        OR  (Holidays.Startdate <= '2014/04/28' AND Holidays.Enddate >= '2014/04/28') 
        OR  (Holidays.StartDate = '2014/04/28' AND Holidays.EndDate = '2014/04/30')
    )
```

Also avoid using Sql server key words as your column names, if you do have some use square brackets `[]` around them when using them in your sql.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE A AND B AND C OR D AND E OR F AND G
```

Is treated the same as

```
WHERE (A AND B AND C) OR (D AND E) OR (F AND G)
```

So if any of your date comparisons other than the first one are in fact true, then the entire `WHERE` clause is satisfied.

And, by the way, it looks like you're trying to find whether two date ranges overlap, and doing it in a very complex matter. You should only need to do two comparisons. Two date ranges overlap if:

- The first range starts before the end of the second range, and
- The second range starts before the end of the first range

So, something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) JobRoleID
    FROM        Employees
    RIGHT JOIN  Holidays
    ON          Employees.ID = Holidays.EmployeeID
    WHERE       Holidays.Status <> 'Declined' AND Holidays.Status <> 'Cancelled'
    AND    Holidays.StartDate <= '20140430' AND '20140428' <= Holidays.EndDate
```

Should be the equivalent of your multiple comparisons.